# animation execute before direction up

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I using plugin one pagescroll fullpage.js.

How to use animation before direction up.

> ```
>  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
>
> if (index == 4 && direction == 'up'){
>
>
>             $('.nave-space').tween({    left:{
>   start: 100,
>   stop: 200,
>   time: 0,
>   units: 'px',
>   duration: 5,
>   // effect:'bounceOut'    },
>   backgroundSize:{
>   start: '10% 10%',
>   stop: '100% 100%',
>   time: 0,
>   duration: 10,
>   effect:'easeInOut',
> }
> ```
>
> }); $.play();
>             }
>
> }

I need help.

Comment: ??? So, remove or replace the "up" condition. On which condition would you like to use the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is how to chain multiple animations one after the other. I am not sure about the specifics about this plugin but generally the idea is that you can queue animations() or you can add one animation in the complete function of another animation.

You can find more about this here:

- [jQuery .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)
- [Multiple sequence of animations](http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/10/managing-multiple-animation-sequences_6039.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible right now.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/340) about it in the github repository of the plugin.

It would require an `beforeLeave` callback.